# On hovering mouse to close button hand is not appearing

Tags: javascript, html

I have written piece of javascript for close button, but when i hover my mouse to close button mouse icon is not changing to hand, so i am not able to close it, however hand appears at some points of the close button
I am facing this issue on firefox and chrome
IE is working fine

Below is some part of it

```
href="javascript:closeWin()"   
keephref="javascript:closeWin()"   
style="cursor: default;
```

Below is its css

```
element.style {
  cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Is the css above you are also declaring within your stylesheet?

Answer (score 5):

The default is the normal arrow. Pointer is the hand.

```
style="cursor: pointer;


element.style {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: No need if the tag is A

Answer (score 4):

Add CSS `cursor:pointer;` which shows a pointing hand cursor.

If you are using `<a>` tag then dont add `cursor:default;` to it because an `<a>` tag already displays pointing cursor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show hand cursor use this CSS for your close anchor

```
a.close {
    cursor: default; /* modern browsers */
    cursor: hand;    /* old IE - property is ignored by others */
}
```

Comment: No need for any CSS if the tag is `A`

Answer (score 0):

If the tag is a link, remove the style since the href will give the hand

```
<a href="#" onclick="closeWin(); return false">Close</a>
```

I do not know what you need the keephref for, but it is not recommended to use javascript: protocol for a link

Answer (score 0):

As AlienArrays and Zword said, the `default` cursor means normal arrow cursor.
If you want the default browser behaviour over an element, use:

```
style="cursor: auto;"
```

You can also use the `pointer` value if you want to force "hand" style cursor, ie. to indicate that something that normally is not clickable will perform an action when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can check :hover attribute in css

```
#element :hover
{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```